# Image_tag in application helper add unwanted concatenation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have an ERB test code to generate HTML image tag but it kept adding "/images/ " on the HTML. What did I do wrong?

```
<label class="pic_s" for="pic_4"><div><img alt="Download_link" src="/images/
    https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Download_link.png" /></div></label>

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Download_link.png
```

This is the ERB code:

```
<%= gallery_thumbnails(image.to_param, "pic_#{idx}") %>
<%= image %>
```

And the application helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def gallery_thumbnails(image, idx)
     content_tag :label, { :for => idx, :class => 'pic_s' } do
        content_tag :div do
          image_tag image
        end
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: what `image.to_param` returns?

Comment: It returns the intended result:<https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Download_link.png>?

Comment: Editing ERB to <%= gallery_thumbnails(image.gsub(' ',''), "pic_#{idx}") %>  fixed it, no more extra "/images". But I still don't understand why the extra space cause ERB to add "/images/" in the html.

Comment: Your code works for me.. Not sure what is wrong with your code..

Comment: can u pass the `image` instead of `image.to_param`?

Comment: your rails version?

Comment: Rails 2.3.17. Removing the whitespaces with gsub(" ","") works. But I still don't understand why the extra space caused ERB to behave that way.

Comment: Ok. I never worked on Rails 2 projects. So not sure how was thing back then.

Answer (score 0):

Using Rails 2.3.17. Removed the whitespaces and the problem goes away.

```
<%= gallery_thumbnails(image.gsub(' ',''), "pic_#{idx}") %>
```